# How do I register a generic class to be resolved when the generic argument is based on a certain type? 

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

How do I register `IPetFactory<TPet>` to be resolved with `DefaultPetFactory<TPet>` where `TPet` can be any class based on `Pet` in the example below?

I'd like to be able to resolve `IPetFactory<Dog>` with `DefaultPetFactory<Dog>`.

I've just found examples using `BasedOn` where the Factory itself is based on a class, not the generic argument.

```
class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Fish : Pet {}
class Dog : Pet {}
class Cat : Pet { }


interface IPetFactory<TPet>  where TPet : Pet;
class DefaultPetFactory<TPet> : IPetFactory<Pet> where TPet : Pet
{
    // default implementation
}
```

*My real implementation has a lot of classes based on Pet so I'm looking for a more generic approach than just calling register on each of them.*

### EDIT:

I found out the problem wasn't what I thought it was. It was due to the generic arguments and an exception of “the arity of the generic type definition” which caused my problems.

And I over-simplified my example. In my real implementation I have to generic arguments and it turns out Windsor need the the same generic parameters to be able to resolve the type.

If I do like this it won't work.

```
class Owner
{

}

class DefaultPetFactory<TPet> : IPetFactory<Owner, TPet> where TPet : Pet
{
    // default implementation
}
```

If I do like this it will:

```
class DefaultPetFactory<TOwner, TPet> : IPetFactory<TOwner, TPet> 
    where TOwner : Owner
    where TPet : Pet
{
    // default implementation
}
```

If anyone has a better solution to this, preferably with the registrations it's appreciated. I don't like to change my classes to make the registration work.

Comment: I may be missing something but what's exactly wrong with using `BasedOn` here?

Comment: The problem wasn't what I thought it was.. See my update in the  question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(For the updated question)*

[There is a ticket in Windsor's issue tracker](http://issues.castleproject.org/issue/IOC-302) to support scenarios like that (feel free to vote for it), but in general this is something very hard to implement... generically (no pun intended), and as far as I know no container currently supports it.

In Windsor 3 you can workaround it by implementing a new interface called `IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy` doing roughly the following (untested, I'm writing this from memory):

```
public class PetMatcher: IGenericImplementationMatchingStrategy
{
   public Type[] GetGenericArguments(ComponentModel model, CreationContext context)
   {
      if (SomePreconditionToMakeSureThatsReallyTheScenarioDescribedAbove() == false )
      {
         return null;// which will fallback to default behaviour
      }
      // implementation needs just one generic arg, second of two the interface has
      return new[]{ context.GenericArguments[1] };
   }
}
```

You then register this as follows:

```
Container.Register(
    Classes.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(IPetFactory<,>)).BasedOn(typeof(IPetFactory<,>))
        .WithServiceBase()
        .Configure(
            c => c.ExtendedProperties(
                Property.ForKey(ComponentModel.GenericImplementationMatchingStrategy)
                    .Eq(new PetMatcher()))));
```

Comment: It's not a big trade-off really so I changed my code. I dont' think it's a big issue either. Thank you for your time!

Comment: " and as far as I know no container currently supports it.". As a mather of fact, Autofac has this feature for over a year (and Simple Injector will for the coming release). It is indeed not easy to implement it.

Comment: Does it? That's interesting. I did however check it in the other direction only (when the class has more generic parameters than interface)